Cambiar el tipo de los valores que retorna un array PHP
Estoy usando phpstan para analizar mi código.
Con lo siguiente tendría un error con el tipo que devuelve MainService::get().
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class AuxService
{

    /**
     * @param array<string,mixed> $arr
     * @return array<string,mixed>
     */
    public static function doSomething(array $arr): array
    {
        // ...

        return $arr;
    }
}

class MainService
{

    /**
     *
     * @return array<string,int>
     */
    public static function get(): array
    {
        $arr = [
            'apple' => 5,
            'pear'  => 3,
        ];

        $output = AuxService::doSomething($arr);

        // TODO: cast the values type to int ?

        return $output;
    }
}

$result = MainService::get(); // expected: array<string,int>

Si devuelvo directamente lo que me devuelve la llamada AuxService::doSomething($arr); no puedo indicar que la salida de MainService::get() es de tipo array<string,int> sino la propia de la devolución de la llamada anterior: array<string,mixed>, aunque el tipo real del dato sea un int.
¿Hay una forma de solucionarlo sin tener que devolver un array<string,mixed>?
He intentado un casting de los valores del array en el lugar del TODO:
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_int($value)) {
            unset($output[$key]);
        }
    }

En este caso PHPStan me indica como error que no puedo casterar un tipo mixed a int.

Editado:

He intentado remover los valores del array que no sean int ya que deben serlo:
    foreach ($output as $key => &$value) {
        if (!is_int($value)) {
            unset($output[$key]);
        }
    }

Aquí el error es que la devolución de AuxService::doSomething($arr); debería ser array<string, int> pero es array<string, mixed>.

Hola. Te recomendaría leer el apartado Narrowing Types en la doc de PHPStan. Ellos recomiendan escribir funciones que retornen el tipo preciso, o usar Tipos Avanzados de PHPDoc en @param y @return o usar Genéricos.

Opción 1: Documentar la variable
Si solo te interesa que el validador no de error (y te queres arriesgar a que tu código genere un error) podes hacer lo siguiente:

Indicar que la variable $output es del tipo array<string,int>

Ejemplo
class MainService
{

    /**
     *
     * @return array<string,int>
     */
    public static function get(): array
    {
        $arr = [
            'apple' => 5,
            'pear'  => 3,
        ];

        /**
         * @var array<string,int>
         */
        $output = AuxService::doSomething($arr);

        return $output;
    }
}

Demo

Opción 2: Analizar el arreglo
Para asegurarte de que estas recibiendo y devolviendo los datos en el formato correcto podes:

Crear una variable, por ejemplo, $aux = [];
Recorrer el arreglo $output
Verificar que el $value sea un int

Ejemplo:
class MainService
{

    /**
     *
     * @return array<string,int>
     */
    public static function get(): array
    {
        $arr = [
            'apple' => 5,
            'pear'  => 3,
        ];

        //
        $output = AuxService::doSomething($arr);

        //
        $aux = [];
        foreach($output as $key => $value) {
            //
            if (is_int($value)) $aux[$key] = $value;
            else {
                // @TODO Throw new Exception ?
            }
        }

        return $aux;
    }
}

Demo

Para mí caso concreto cualquiera de las dos soluciones que planteas me parece válida: los valores del array antes de pasar al servicio auxiliar son de tipo int y este solo va a ordenar el array en base a sus llaves. La segunda solución, con una excepción personalizada, me parece la mejor opción en general.
